# Gulp 'watch' not saving files rendered with gulp-swig

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, swig-template

I've used Gulp a number of times but this problem has me totally stumped. I have a `render` task to save an HTML template piped through `gulp-swig`. It works perfectly fine when invoked manually via `gulp render` but will not save when the task is triggered by `gulp.watch`. So, to clarify, the watcher *does* trigger the task but the rendered file doesn't actually get saved to its destination.

I've boiled the problem down to the following, removing all other tasks from my gulpfile, axed plumber, context data, etc. Any help appreciated!

```
var gulp        = require( 'gulp' ),
    browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create(),
    rename      = require( 'gulp-rename' ),
    swig        = require( 'gulp-swig' ),
    reload      = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task( 'render', function() {
    return gulp.src( './dev/template.html' )
        .pipe( swig() )
        .pipe( rename( 'index.html' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './preview' ) )
        .on( 'end', reload );
});

gulp.task( 'serve', function() {
    browserSync.init( { server: './preview' } );

    gulp.watch( './dev/*.html',  [ 'render' ] );
});

gulp.task( 'default', [ 'serve' ] );
```

Comment: I've now confirmed that the `swig()` module is the culprit, but no solution yet..

Answer (score 1):

Duh, got it working. It appears that swig caches the template by default (?) so it was in fact saving the file but it was identical. I noticed a 'cache' option in another (unrelated) post about swig which did the trick. So, I needed to pass in an options object, like so:

```
        .pipe( swig({ 
            defaults: { cache: false }
        }) )
```